# Magento 2 Disable Shipping Method Based on Total

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I created a custom shipping module and I want to disable it at checkout if the total is less than 100.  I created an Observer called DisablePayment.php:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    
    class DisablePayment implements ObserverInterface
    {
    
      public function execute( Observer $observer )
      {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cartObj = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $grandTotal = $cartObj->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); 
    
        if($method_instance == 'methodcode')
        {
          $checkoutLimit = 100;
          $total = $grandTotal;
    
          if($checkoutLimit > $total)
          {
            $result->setData('is_available', false);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I can't get this to work. Do I need to do anything else?

Thanks,
Stan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom shipping method module. there is a model defined in app/code/vendorname/packagename/etc/config.xml

In your custom shipping model file add below code.

```
<?php

namespace Stackoverflow\Customshipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Custom extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{

   ......
   
   ......
   
   ......
   
   protected $cart;
   
   public function __construct(
        ......
        ......
        
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        ......
        ......
    ) {
        ......
        $this->cart = $cart;
       ......
    }
    
    
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
       ......
       
       ......
       
        $subTotal = $this->cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
        if($subTotal < 100){
             return false;
        }
        
        ......
         
        ......
        
    }
    
    ......
    
    ......

}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!!